# Boot repair on raid after crashed system-upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, raid

I found it difficult to find an answer to this problem without specific step by step advice.

During an Ubuntu system update an error occurred and it froze my PC. After a forced shutdown I encountered the GRUB terminal (minimal BASH-like editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.) and couldn't boot. I created a USB ISO of boot repair with unetbootin.

Ran boot repair and it said "RAID detected. You may want to retry after installing the [mdadm] packages. (`sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes mdadm --no-installs-recommends`)

I pressed "ok" and I was taken to the main boot repair screen. I ran "recommended repair". After a few moment I get the message,

> dpkg-error detected. Please open terminal then type the following command:
>
> `sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root" dpkg --configure -a`

The reply I had was:

> chroot: cannot change root directory to mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root: No such file or directory

I would appreciate any advice that you have as to where to go from here?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version where you upgrading? And what kind of raid do you have?

Comment: I was upgrading the latest 32-bit Ubuntu version. I'm not sure of what Raid I have.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lsblk -f` to your question when you have booted with the live CD?

Comment: Maybe you can changeroot into the system with a normal LIve-CD? [Automate chroot into broken system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157107)

Comment: I am using a small PC laptop that doesnt have a cd drive, so I've been attempting to boot Ubuntu live from USB. When I try the command above rubo77, it says 'cannot find command 'sudo'

Comment: then you didnt start the live CD. Please start the whole live CD by selecting "Test Ubuntu without install"